# how to pass argument(Null) and Hard coded value in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

If I have a query which runs on SQL which is :

```
String contactWhere = " UNION SELECT FoldContact.FoldRSN,NULL PeopleRSNCode,'A' FileIndicator from People,Contact"
```

But how we pass **NULL PeopleRSNCrypt** and **'A' FIleIndicator** in jooq. if we have

```
SelectQuery<Record> selectQuery = create.selectQuery();
        selectQuery.addSelect(Contact.FOLD_CONTACT.FOLD_RSN);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Factory.value("A").as("FIleIndicator")` and `Factory.inline(null).as("PeopleRSNCrypt")`

Comment: but how and where to give Column name

Comment: Factory class is it a part of jooq lib?

Comment: @GauravRatnawat Yes: https://www.jooq.org/doc/2.6/manual/sql-building/factory/